# iPhone image problems

Tags: iphone, memory, image, alloc

I'm having frequent crashes on iOS 4.0 within my application due to excessive memory. Instruments tells me that it's category is "Malloc 600KB" and the responsible library is ImageIO and the responsible caller is ImageIO_Malloc. I'm using lots of images in this app but no more than I have used in other applications. It's odd because if I run the same code on 3.0 then I have no real problems and on 4.0 sometimes it will jump from 5MB to 30MB Memory even if I haven't touched it and it hasn't loaded any new images (as far as my knowledge goes).

Does anyone have any ideas or know how I might find the source of the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you by any chance doing things like reading in or converting images *in a loop*?

Comment: You may want to post how you are allocating the images, and how you are using them exactly (i.e. loading them all at once in a scrollview, in a tableview, etc)

Comment: Also worth noting is whether you're doing any background threading at all, anywhere.

Comment: I have the same exact question and would love to hear an answer. My app is an image gallery which uses a scroll view to display images just like the Photos app. Every time i scroll, it increases an object in the category "Malloc 600KB" and obviously leads to crash eventually when it runs out of memory.